# I have this issue with reseting the form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to do the if condition when requesting for reseting the form. When the condition is confirmed the form will be reset, if not it won't be reset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>form events</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1250">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onreset="FormReset()" name="form1">
            <input type="text" name="T1" size="20"  /><br />
            <input type="reset" name="res1=" value="reset" /><br />
        </form>
        <script language="javascript">
            function FormReset(){
              if(confirm("Do you wish to reset your data?")){
                  return true;
                  }
              else return false; 
              }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to return the function's value: `onreset="return FormReset()"`

Comment: Thanks man! You've made my day. It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>form events</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1250" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form1" id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="T1" size="20" /><br />
      <input
        type="button"
        onclick="FormReset()"
        name="res1="
        value="reset"
      /><br />
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
      function FormReset() {
        if (confirm("Do you wish to reset your data?")) {
          document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        } 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Checkout Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-jackson-6kxit?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)